# Article "the" usage with word "development"

Tags: articles, definite-article

I'm trying to translate a topic of my scientific work. I came up with 3 options:

> 1. modern approaches to the development of web applications
> 2. modern approaches to development of the web applications
> 3. modern approaches to the development of the web applications

But I'm not sure which one is grammaticly right. Can you tell me what option do I choce and why?

Comment: The first one seems better if you don't talk about about some specific web applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I believe that each use of *the* is grammatically correct.
In order to determine which one is "correct", we need more context. In other words, you have to choose the one that is most appropriate for your work.
I will help you understand what each one implies.

1. Including *the* in *the development* can imply that there is *one* kind of development, or that you had a particular development in mind (and you introduced it earlier). Omitting *the* from *the web applications* implies that you are speaking broadly about web applications in general.
2. Omitting *the*  from *the development* can imply that you are talking about unspecified/unnamed developments of *the web applications*. Including *the* in *the web applications*  suggests that you have certain *web applications* in mind, and it also suggests that you introduced it earlier in the work/paragraph.
3. Including *the* in *the development* can imply that there is *one* kind of development, or that you had a particular development in mind (and you introduced it earlier). Including *the* in *the web applications* implies that you are talking about certain applications which you introduced earlier.

[Here is one](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/definite-article/) resource that might help you understand the article *the*. You can search for others online.

Comment: What to you mean "one kind of development"? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Basically, In my work I am considering processes and actual ways which are applied to web development nowdays. According to your anser, I'm thinking about either 1-st option, or let's call it 4-th opt.: without article in both cases. So what would you suggest to choose?

Comment: "one kind of development" means like there is only one kind method people are using to make this kind of development. Or one kind of philosophy about the development. That is probably not the case. But this was just one possibility. It can also refer to the field "development" of web applications. If I really had to choose, I would say option 1., because if you are not speaking about a particular type of development, then it should be clear to the reader that you are speaking broadly about the field of development. Since you are considering many web applications, I would drop "the".