# I am unsure whether to have "the" before the structure "A of B". - (The) exclusion of the women in certain jobs is a major issue

Tags: usage, definite-article

**Example 1**

A: Those women are facing unemployment.

> (1) B: The exclusion of the women in certain jobs is a major issue.

> (2) B: Exclusion of the women in certain jobs is a major issue.

Is there a difference between the two variants?

**Example 2**

> (1) "The development of the country's economy is fast."

> (2) "Development of the country's economy is fast."

Is there a difference between the two variants?

---

I am unsure whether to have "the" before the structure "A of B".

Should it be "A of B" or "the A of B"?

Comment: Which do you think it should be, and how have you reached that opinion?

Comment: Women are excluded **from** certain jobs.

Comment: And why not *The country’s economy is developing fast*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The definite article before “of-phrases”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148645/the-definite-article-before-of-phrases) Also [Article "the" usage with word "development"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94619/article-the-usage-with-word-development) and doubtless many more.

Comment: In the first case, "Exclusion _of women_ [from] certain jobs..." means exclusion of _all_ women, such as certain religions' priesthood. "Exclusion of _the women_  [from] certain jobs..." means exclusion of _a particular subset of women_, previously defined by _Those women are facing unemployment._

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, natural, and acceptable and mean nearly the same thing.

> (1) B: The exclusion of the women in certain jobs is a major issue.

This almost has an implication of some particular exclusion you are referring to, or have already referred to. Perhaps you have discussed the nature of the exclusion before so now "the exclusion" serves to point to specifically that variant of exclusion that you talked about.

> (2) B: Exclusion of the women in certain jobs is a major issue.

This implies that exclusion generally, not necessarily any specific exclusion or type / subset of exclusion, is a major issue. This can still work even if you are talking about a specific type of exclusion that you referenced earlier, but it feels a bit more general or able to be a standalone.

The difference between 1. and 2. is very nuanced and the implication is more of connotation, not a hard rule. In practice, it doesn't matter which one you choose.

The comments on other ways to improve the sentence are also correct. These are probably more relevant to the sentences given than adding the "the" or not.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not specific to the "of" structure. In general, when you use "the" before a plural noun, it means that that noun refers to some subgroup that is identified by context, either the current sentence or previously. When you don't use "the", it means all things described by the noun.

So for example, suppose you said, "Our store does not accept checks from out of town banks. Checks are not secure." That would mean that checks in general are not secure, and so you put a restriction on their use. But if you said, "our store does not accept checks from out of town banks. The checks are not secure", that would mean that checks from out of town banks are not secure. You may or may not believe that checks from in-town banks are secure.

In your examples, nothing in the sentences themselves says what subgroup is meant by "the". If you had talked about some other form of exclusion of women, and then said, "the exclusion of women from certain jobs is a major issue", I would take that to mean that exclusion of women from something else is not a major issue, or at least that you aren't talking about that right now. But realistically, the larger group and the subgroup in these cases is likely the same, so that the use of the word "the" makes no difference to the meaning.